# How to do I make the circle shape fixed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make a filter system just like Instagram and Snapchat what i am trying to do is make the center circle fixed at center while the image slidable just like Instagram and Snapchat.

Stack overflow told me to make this bigger so

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to create a filter system similar to Instagram and Snapchat. What I am attempting to achieve is to have a fixed center circle on the screen. This circle will serve as a reference point for various filters and effects.

I have been researching and experimenting with different methods, but I am facing some challenges in making this fixed circle interactive and ensuring that the filters are applied accurately based on its position and size.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:pretend/common/constants.dart';
import 'package:pretend/common/height_spacer.dart';
import 'package:pretend/common/width_spacer.dart';
import 'package:pretend/features/NFT/screens/caption_screen.dart';
import 'package:pretend/features/create/controllers/audio_controller.dart';

import 'audio_listing_screen.dart';

class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/video-screen';
  const VideoScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoScreen> createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
  int selectedImageIndex = 0;
  double previousProgressValue = 1.0;
  Timer? countdownTimer;
  int remainingSeconds = 0;

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    viewportFraction: 0.2, // Adjust this fraction as needed
  );

  void startCountdown(Duration? duration, int selectedImageIndex) {
    if (duration != null) {
      final totalSeconds = duration.inSeconds;
      countdownTimer = Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(seconds: 1),
        (timer) {
          setState(() {
            remainingSeconds = totalSeconds - timer.tick;
          });

          if (remainingSeconds <= 0) {
            // Timer reached zero, navigate to another screen
            timer.cancel();
            Future.delayed(
              const Duration(seconds: 1),
              () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  CaptionScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: AppConstants.gridviewImages[selectedImageIndex],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Get.find<AudioController>().disposeAudioResources();
        Get.find<AudioController>().onInit();
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const HeightSpacer(size: 50),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // setState(() {
                  //   selectedImageIndex = -1;
                  // });
                },

                child: selectedImageIndex != -1
                    ? Stack(
                        children: [
                          Image.network(
                            AppConstants.gridviewImages[selectedImageIndex],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            height: double.infinity,
                            width: double.infinity,
                          ),
                          Obx(
                            () {
                              final selectedAudioFilePath =
                                  Get.find<AudioController>()
                                      .selectedAudioFilePath
                                      .value;

                              return selectedAudioFilePath == ''
                                  ? const SizedBox()
                                  : Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 160.w,
                                            height: 40.h,
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 18, vertical: 4),
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 10),
                                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                            ),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                SvgPicture.asset(
                                                    AppConstants.wavesSvg),
                                                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                                InkWell(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    Get.find<AudioController>()
                                                        .playAudioFile(
                                                      Get.find<
                                                              AudioController>()
                                                          .selectedAudioFromSaved
                                                          .value,
                                                      1,
                                                    );
                                                    startCountdown(
                                                        Get.find<
                                                                AudioController>()
                                                            .savedAudioTotalDuration,
                                                        selectedImageIndex);
                                                  },
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Audio $selectedAudioFilePath',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 12.sp,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );

                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : Container(),

              ),
            ),
            const HeightSpacer(size: 20),
            // CircularProgressBar(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 80.0,
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: pageController,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedImageIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                itemCount: AppConstants.gridviewImages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedImageIndex = index;
                      });
                      pageController.animateToPage(
                        index,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
                      pageController.animateToPage(
                        index,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        // selectedImageIndex == index
                        //     ? Obx(() {
                        //         return SizedBox(
                        //           width: 70.w,
                        //           height: 110.h,
                        //           child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        //             strokeWidth: 1,
                        //             value: Get.find<AudioController>()
                        //                 .savedAudioProgress
                        //                 .value,
                        //           ),
                        //         );
                        //       })
                        //     : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                        Container(
                          width: 55.w,
                          height: 50.h,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: selectedImageIndex == index
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              width: 2.0,
                            ),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                AppConstants.gridviewImages[index],
                                scale: 10,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const HeightSpacer(size: 40),
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.w),
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                // Padding(
                //   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                //   child: InkWell(
                //     onTap: () {
                //       showModalBottomSheet(
                //         context: context,
                //         builder: (context) {
                //           return AudioListBottomSheet(
                //             index: selectedImageIndex,
                //           );
                //         },
                //       );
                //     },
                //     child: SvgPicture.asset(AppConstants.songsSvg),
                //   ),
                // ),
                const WidthSpacer(width: 90),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Video',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                        fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                      ),
                    ),
                    const WidthSpacer(width: 30),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        // Navigator.push(
                        //   context,
                        //   MaterialPageRoute(
                        //     builder: (context) => BottomBar(page: 2),
                        //   ),
                        // );
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const AudioListingScreen(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Voice',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 14.sp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const HeightSpacer(size: 40),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Center while the images slidable

[image]

Comment: for any non-trivial layouts you should most likely use `CustomMultiChildLayout` or `Flow` widgets